# (Addon domain) Hosting multiple websites on single hosting account

Tags: web-hosting, multiple-domains

I have an preexisting website, www.main.com.
Using, cpanel I set up a addon domain, www.personal.com, but Cpanel also setup a subdomain, www.personal.main.com, which I don't want. So I just redirected www.personal.main.com to www.main.com.

Both main.com and personal.com are both registered.

First question, I don't want main.com and personal.com to be connected in anyway. So I don't want the other one to show up a search engine result when searching for the other one. Since I've already redirected personal.main.com back to main.com, will this show up in a search result? If so how can I do this so it doesn't show up and the two are completely separate.

Second question, what is the correct way of hosting two websites on a single hosting server? www.main.com is located in /public_html/ and I have setup www.personal.com in /personal.com/.

Currently both websites, main.com and personal.com are up and running without an issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you bother redirecting the subdomain?  It is part of the way cpanel sets them up. If you don't want to use it, just don't use it.  Don't tell anyone about it, don't link to it.  Just leave it.

Your two domains are already connected by being on the same server.  Many of the online DNS tools will show all the domains on a specific server. But again, what makes you think that a search for main.com will in any way connect to personal.com?  Unless you cross link them or they have conent that is very similar they will be completely separate.

Your way of setting up the sites will work.  Another way is to have main.com in /public_html and personal.com in /public_html/personal.com but since you seem worried about connecting the two you may not like that as going to main.com/personal.com will show the personal.com website.

If both sites are up and running without any issues just leave it be.